# Nginx Ingress Controller can't find nodes on Google Kubernetes Engine

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, kubernetes-ingress, nginx-ingress

I installed a "nginx ingress controller" on my GKE cluster.
I followed [this guide](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/deploy/) to install the nginx ingress controller in the GKE.

When deploying resources for the service and ingress resource I realized that the ingress controller was at `0/1`
[image]

Events telling me:

```
0/1 nodes are available: 1 node(s) didn't match node selector.
```

Now I checked the yaml/describe: https://pastebin.com/QG3GKxh1
And found that:

```
nodeSelector:
    kubernetes.io/os: linux
```

Which looks fine in my opinion. Since I just used the command of the guide to install the controller I have no idea what went wrong from my side.

### Solution:

The provided answer showed me the way. My node was labeled with `beta.kubernetes/io: linux` while the controller was looking for `kubernetes/io: linux`.
Renaming the `nodeSelector` in the controller worked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`nodeSelector` is used to constraint the nodes on which your Pods can be scheduled.

With:

```
nodeSelector:
    kubernetes.io/os: linux
```

You are saying that Pods must be assigned to a node that has the label
`kubernetes.io/os: linux`. If none of your nodes has that label, the Pod will never get scheduled.

Removing the selector from the nginx ingress controller or adding the label `kubernetes.io/os: linux` to any node should fix your issue.

Comment: I see in my nodes yaml that it has the following label:
`beta.kubernetes.io/os: linux`. So I simply need to change that label in the controller right?

Comment: Yes, you can modify the yaml definition so that `beta.kubernetes.io/os: linux` is the value for the node selector or you can remove the node selector altogether if you don't need any constraints on the node.

Comment: If you prefer to attach the label to your nodes rather than modifying your Pod specification, you can attach the label to a node like this: `kubectl label nodes [NODE_NAME] kubernetes.io/os=linux` (And you can double check that the label has been attached: `kubectl get nodes --show-labels`)